# Is there any way to auto-save all my entered text in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, text-editing

I love the idea that gmail and Stackoverflow record my message so when I come again to that tab or draft I can find all the text that I have typed earlier already filled in.

On Internet not every site has this feature. I hope to get a plugin which stores what I type and as long as I have not submitted the form it will store the text I have written.

This way I can make safe that a big message would be saved if my browser got any trouble or mistakenly I refreshed the browser.

Somebody knows any plugin that will store the information of what I typed in forms in the browser?

Answer (score 4):

[Lazarus Form Recovery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/lazarus-form-recovery/) is the best one I have used.

It allows lots of options for what to store, when, how long, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are several Firefox add-on out there.e.g. **[Textarea Cache](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/textarea-cache/)**.

[image]

Which can auto save any text you've typed in any Textarea fields like this Or in WYSIWYG editors.